# Help setting up money system in game maker

Tags: game-maker

I am trying to make a clicker game where one button makes the item and then one button sells the item. My problem is that I don't know how to make the one button stop selling when it reaches 0 items to sell. My code for the selling of the item as of right now looks like this in game maker:

```
///Sell items 
global.money+=global.PC 
global.items-=global.PC
```

It works to subtract per click, but once it reaches 0, it keeps going in to negatives. I am very new to this so forgive my asking probably simple questions.

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, but check if it's above 0 before subtracting. Look for the `if` instruction. Basically: if the value is above 0, perform the 'transaction'.

Comment: Take a look at my C# implementation: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122959/rpg-currency-system

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go with most short and simple method.

```
//Sell items 

global.money+=global.PC * (global.items > 0)

global.items-=global.PC * (global.items > 0)
```

Comment: While a valid possibility, this is not something I would suggest to a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional IF statement.

```
// First, check IF there are enough items left to sell
if (global.items >= global.PC) {
    // Condition passed -- Sell items now
    global.money+=global.PC 
    global.items-=global.PC 
}
```

If the condition fails, the code will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
global.items = 10
if (global.items >= 1) {
    // There are more than one item, so it passes.
    global.money+=global.PC 
    global.items-=global.PC 
} else
{
draw.text"No more items" //Im at work, so i cant get on game maker to test the draw. text function, but you get the idea here.
}
```

This would be my solution to your problem, i have implemented systems like this before in my games. I hope it helps.